# Magical Record : Calculate data with calculations

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, magicalrecord

I knew Magical Record has supported Aggregate Operations like sum:, max:

But is there any way to make some simple calculations like :

`sum: attributes * other_attributes`

If we knew these attributes 's value are NSNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the result of your both request in 2 variables. then you do the operation.